# How to show svg symbol from external file after appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, svg, appendchild, clonenode

So, basically i want to use  to create some component which contains svg symbol.

```
<button onclick="openWindow('#my-template')">Open Template</button>
<template id="my-template">
    <div id="my-div">
        <div>My fancy stuff</div>
        <svg>
            <use href="/svg/icons.svg#my-icon"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</template>
```

As you see i refer to external svg icons file `<use href="/svg/icons.svg#my-icon"/>` which works perfect in regular html. But then i want to do this basic javascript function, icon itself is not visible after appending to DOM.

```
function openWindow(e) {
    let content = document.querySelector(e).content;
    document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
}
```

So basically all what it does is cloning template content and appending to document body. It works perfectly except that icon itself is not rendered. There is a svg node in DOM created, but icon is not visible on the screen.
When i include inline `<svg>` document with symbols listed in my current HTML document and refer to icon with `<use href="#i-my-icon"/>` it works as expected. Icon is visible. How can i be able still to use external `.svg` file in this case? I don't want to deal with inlining svg icons directly or including icon set in every html document or template.

Comment: I think we're going to need a complete [mcve] here.

Comment: Where can i create complete example? Codepen doen't allow to add additional file like `icons.svg` for example. I would create booth - working and non-working samples.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using an object:

```js
function openWindow(e) {
    let content = document.querySelector(e).content;
    document.body.appendChild(content.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openWindow('#my-template')">Open Template</button>
<template id="my-template">
    <div id="my-div">
        <div>My fancy stuff</div>
<object id="svgContent" type="image/svg+xml"
data="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat">
</object>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Tnx. Your example works. I was trying object before, but looks like i made some mistake and it was not working.
Are `<object>` idiomatic way to solve this kind of task?

Comment: Ouh.. it looks your `cat.svg` file doesn't use `<symbol>'s`. Will make some research in this area.